# Bootstrap correctly imported but styles not working

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-4, twig

I followed the instructions on how to import bootstrap on symfony but it doesn't seem to import any styles.

I tried to import it in different blocks and divs, but it doesn't seem to do anything. 
I'm using Webpack encore, and it compiles everytime correctly.

My app.js file:

```
// any CSS you require will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
require('../css/app.css');
require('chartist/dist/chartist.css');
const Chartist = require('chartist');
window.Chartist = Chartist;

// Need jQuery? Install it with "yarn add jquery", then uncomment to require it.
const $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $;

// this "modifies" the jquery module: adding behavior to it
// the bootstrap module doesn't export/return anything
require('bootstrap');
```

My twig template (which is **not** the base template):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<h1>
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
</h1>

{% block head %}
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul id="menu" class="navbar">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">First Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Third Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fourth Entry</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}


    <div class="container">

        <div class="app-chartist" data-url="{{ path('data') }}"></div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Only the chartist styles are imported, otherwise none whatsoever.

Is there a possibility of "style conflicts" between bootstrap and chartist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it working with scss.

In my **app.js** file:

```
require('../css/app.scss');
const $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
require('bootstrap');
```

That last line above imports the bootstrap **javascript**

Then in my **app.scss** file:

```
// optionally customize some Bootstrap variables
$primary: darken(#428bca, 20%);
$dark: lighten(black,10%);
$light: lighten($dark, 65%);
$white: darken(#FFFFFF, 5%);

// the ~ allows you to reference things in node_modules
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

The last line above is where the bootstrap **styles** are imported.